# Split python string every nth character iterating over starting character

Tags: python, string, loops

I'm trying to find an elegant way to split a python string every nth character, iterating over which character to start with.

For example, suppose I have a string containing the following:

```
ANDTLGY
```

I want to split the string into a set of 3 characters looking like this:

```
['AND','NDT','DTL','TLG','LGY']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a='ANDTLGY'
def nlength_parts(a,n):
    return map(''.join,zip(*[a[i:] for i in range(n)]))

print nlength_parts(a,3)
```

hopefully you can explain to the professor how it works ;)

Comment: ... if you cannot explain it to your teacher, when you try you should make sure to use lots of words like "dereferencing" and "observer pattern" and "functional programming"

Comment: In truth, I feel like some explanation would be helpful ... or maybe I should just look up `map` and `zip` myself. :D

Comment: Thank you! All help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 5):

Simple way is to use string slicing together with list comprehensions:

```
s = 'ANDTLGY'
[s[i:i+3] for i in range(len(s)-2)]
#output:
['AND', 'NDT', 'DTL', 'TLG', 'LGY']
```

Comment: nice this also generates the right solution ... who knew there could be so many "right" answers :P +1

Comment: I feel like this is a clean, simple, easily understood solution. +1

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the help!

Comment: @ChrisE you're welcome. You should [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) one of the answers

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
a='ANDTLGY'

def chopper(s,chop=3):
     if len(s) < chop:
        return []
     return [s[0:chop]] + chopper(s[1:],chop)
```

this returns

```
['AND', 'NDT', 'DTL', 'TLG', 'LGY']
```

Comment: @JoranBeasley Many thanks... I like the idea of recursion - and to me this is easier to understand. Others may disagree. Your solution more deep  than mine I feel. Not sure where they would stand on timing however ...

Comment: Liked the recursion :)