# Split and parse (to new file) string every nth character iterating over starting character - python

Tags: python, loops, parsing

I asked a more general approach to this problem in a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38727914/split-python-string-every-nth-character-iterating-over-starting-character) but I am getting stuck with trying to parse out my results to individual files. I want to iterate over a long string, starting at position 1 (python 0) and print out every 100 characters. Then, I want move over one character and start at position 2 (python 1) and repeat the process until I reach the last 100 characters. I want to parse each "100" line chunk into a new file. Here is what I am currently working with:

```
seq = 7524       # I get this number from a raw_input 
read_num=100

for raw_reads in range(100):
    def nlength_parts(seq,read_num):
        return map(''.join,zip(*[seq[i:] for i in range(read_num)]))


f = open('read' + str(raw_reads), 'w')
f.write("read" '\n')
f.write(nlength_parts(seq,read_num))
f.close
```

The error I am constantly getting now it

```
f.write(nlength_parts(seq,read_num))
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Having some issues, any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

After some help, I have made some changes but still not working properly:

```
seq = 7524       # I get this number from a raw_input 
read_num=100

def nlength_parts(seq,read_num):
    return map(''.join,zip(*[seq[i:] for i in range(read_num)]))

for raw_reads in range(100):   # Should be gene length - 100
    f = open('read' + str(raw_reads), 'w')
    f.write("read" + str(raw_reads))
    f.write(nlength_parts)
    f.close
```

---

I may have left out some important variables and definitions to keep my post short but it has caused confusion. I have pasted my entire code below.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys,os
import random
import string

raw = raw_input("Text file: " )

with open(raw) as f:
    joined = "".join(line.strip() for line in f)
    f = open(raw + '.txt', 'w')
    f.write(joined)
    f.closed

seq = str(joined)
read_num = 100

def nlength_parts(seq,read_num):
    return map(''.join,zip(*[seq[i:] for i in range(read_num)]))

for raw_reads in range(100):   # ideally I want range to be len(seq)-100
    f = open('read' + str(raw_reads), 'w')
    f.write("read" + str(raw_reads))
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(str(nlength_parts))
    f.close
```

Comment: Why are you defining your function inside of a for loop. That either makes no sense or I haven't had enough coffee today.

Comment: It may not be the best decision, I admit to that. I am trying to parse out each of the nlength_parts solutions to a new file and can't figure out the best way.

Comment: What I meant about that is it looks like gibberish. What are you trying to do by defining it in a loop, because it will just do the exact same thing as if you took it out of the loop. Also you seem to be garbling your global variables with parameters...

Comment: Yeah also raw_reads is out of scope by the time you reference it the second time

Comment: my code is a mess.....I moved the for loop but still cannot get it to print out each output from my nlength_parts...here is the code now:

Comment: Okay, please edit your post with that, because I can't read code like that

Comment: Sorry about that, edited the original post above

Comment: 2 more problems, what is the string you are trying to slice inside the zip(), because using the [] operator on an int is meaningless. Also, is "readXXX" really the path of the file you are trying to open?

Comment: 1) the string is a file with lines of 50 characters that I want to concatenate into one long string/line, I did this to remove any spaces so that while looping through string and extracting 100 character lines out there wouldn't be any issues and 2) Yes, that is the name format of the text files I want to output

Comment: Did that code work?

Comment: Still having some issues with `with f as open(path, "w"):` with error `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`. I edited my post again

Comment: @ChrisE The correct syntax would be `with open(path, "w") as f:`

Comment: Thank you @Harrison,
@HenryPrickett-Morgan, the code works for parsing out the first 100 lines of the input into a `".txt"` file. I want it now to do that again, starting at position 2 (python 1) and print out characters 2-101 and continue iterating the starting position, until it gets to the last 100 lines, each of these 100 character reads to be a new file labeled `"read1.txt, read2.txt, read3.txt, etc..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit in response to clarifying comment:

Essentially, you want a rolling window of your string. Say `long_string = "012345678901234567890123456789..."` for a total length of 100.

```
In [18]: long_string
Out[18]: '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789'

In [19]: window = 10

In [20]: for i in range(len(long_string) - window +1):
   .....:     chunk = long_string[i:i+window]
   .....:     print(chunk)
   .....:     with open('chunk_' + str(i+1) + '.txt','w') as f:
   .....:         f.write(chunk)
   .....:         
0123456789
1234567890
2345678901
3456789012
4567890123
5678901234
6789012345
7890123456
8901234567
9012345678
0123456789
1234567890
2345678901
3456789012
4567890123
5678901234
6789012345
7890123456
8901234567
9012345678
0123456789
1234567890
2345678901
3456789012
4567890123
5678901234
6789012345
7890123456
8901234567
9012345678
0123456789
1234567890
2345678901
3456789012
4567890123
5678901234
6789012345
7890123456
8901234567
9012345678
0123456789
1234567890
2345678901
3456789012
4567890123
5678901234
6789012345
7890123456
8901234567
9012345678
0123456789
1234567890
2345678901
3456789012
4567890123
5678901234
6789012345
7890123456
8901234567
9012345678
0123456789
1234567890
2345678901
3456789012
4567890123
5678901234
6789012345
7890123456
8901234567
9012345678
0123456789
1234567890
2345678901
3456789012
4567890123
5678901234
6789012345
7890123456
8901234567
9012345678
0123456789
1234567890
2345678901
3456789012
4567890123
5678901234
6789012345
7890123456
8901234567
9012345678
0123456789
```

Finally,

```
In [21]: ls
chunk_10.txt  chunk_20.txt  chunk_30.txt  chunk_40.txt  chunk_50.txt  chunk_60.txt  chunk_70.txt  chunk_80.txt  chunk_90.txt
chunk_11.txt  chunk_21.txt  chunk_31.txt  chunk_41.txt  chunk_51.txt  chunk_61.txt  chunk_71.txt  chunk_81.txt  chunk_91.txt
chunk_12.txt  chunk_22.txt  chunk_32.txt  chunk_42.txt  chunk_52.txt  chunk_62.txt  chunk_72.txt  chunk_82.txt  chunk_9.txt
chunk_13.txt  chunk_23.txt  chunk_33.txt  chunk_43.txt  chunk_53.txt  chunk_63.txt  chunk_73.txt  chunk_83.txt
chunk_14.txt  chunk_24.txt  chunk_34.txt  chunk_44.txt  chunk_54.txt  chunk_64.txt  chunk_74.txt  chunk_84.txt
chunk_15.txt  chunk_25.txt  chunk_35.txt  chunk_45.txt  chunk_55.txt  chunk_65.txt  chunk_75.txt  chunk_85.txt
chunk_16.txt  chunk_26.txt  chunk_36.txt  chunk_46.txt  chunk_56.txt  chunk_66.txt  chunk_76.txt  chunk_86.txt
chunk_17.txt  chunk_27.txt  chunk_37.txt  chunk_47.txt  chunk_57.txt  chunk_67.txt  chunk_77.txt  chunk_87.txt
chunk_18.txt  chunk_28.txt  chunk_38.txt  chunk_48.txt  chunk_58.txt  chunk_68.txt  chunk_78.txt  chunk_88.txt
chunk_19.txt  chunk_29.txt  chunk_39.txt  chunk_49.txt  chunk_59.txt  chunk_69.txt  chunk_79.txt  chunk_89.txt
chunk_1.txt   chunk_2.txt   chunk_3.txt   chunk_4.txt   chunk_5.txt   chunk_6.txt   chunk_7.txt   chunk_8.txt
```

### Original response

I would just treat the string like a file. This lets you avoid any slicing headaches and is pretty straightforward because the file API lets you "read" in chunks easily.

```
In [1]: import io

In [2]: long_string = 'a'*100 + 'b'*100 + 'c'*100 + 'e'*88

In [3]: print(long_string)
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccceeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

In [4]: string_io = io.StringIO(long_string)

In [5]: chunk = string_io.read(100)

In [6]: chunk_no = 1

In [7]: while chunk:
   ....:     print(chunk)
   ....:     with open('chunk_' + str(chunk_no) + '.txt','w') as f:
   ....:         f.write(chunk)
   ....:     chunk = string_io.read(100)
   ....:     chunk_no += 1
   ....:     
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
```

Note, I'm using ipython terminal, so you can use terminal commands inside the interpreter session!

```
In [8]: ls chunk*
chunk_1.txt  chunk_2.txt  chunk_3.txt  chunk_4.txt

In [9]: cat chunk_1.txt
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
In [10]: cat chunk_2.txt
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
In [11]: cat chunk_3.txt
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
In [12]: cat chunk_4.txt
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
In [13]:
```

Comment: What if I have a very long string, something like `"D2G6H9T2FV...."` and I want to chop it into `[i:i+3], [i+1,i+4]....` chunks that yield `"D2G", "2G6", "G6H"`, etc..... and have each of those strings be a separate .txt file like `"D2G"` corresponds to `chunk_1.txt` and '"2G6"` corresponds to `chunk_2.txt`

Comment: @ChrisE Oh, I misunderstood what you were trying to accomplish. You basically want a rolling window of some given size. That's easy. No need for complicated functions, just a simple for-loop will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

1. You define the variables `seq` and `read_num` in the global scope, and then also use the same parameters in your function. What you should be doing is have the names of the parameters in the function definition be different, and then passing those two variables to the function when you call it.
2. When you call nlength_parts, you don't pass it either of the parameters you defined it with and you also lack (). Fix that in conjunction with #1.
3. You don't seem to define the string you are slicing. You slice `seq` in your function, but `seq` is an integer in your code. Is seq the processed output of the file you were talking about in your comment? If so, is it much larger in your actual code?

That being said, I believe this code will do what you want it to do:

```
def nlength_parts(myStr, length, paddingChar=" "):
    if(len(myStr) < length):
        myStr += paddingChar * (length - len(myStr))
    sequences = []
    for i in range(0, len(myStr)-length + 1):
    sequences.append(myStr[i:i+length])
    return(sequences)
foo = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
nlengthfoo = nlength_parts(foo, 10)
for x in range(0, length(nlengthfoo):
    with open("read" + (x+1), "w") as f:
        f.write(nlengthfoo[x])
```

EDIT: Apologies, changed my code in response to your comment.

Comment: I am currently getting stuck at the
   `with f as open(path, "w"):`
still troubleshooting it at the moment

The string I want to slice is `seq`, which is a very long string of characters I want to chop into 100 character segments in a loop, starting at position 0 and moving over one position until the string reaches the last 100 characters

Comment: @ChrisE change it to `with open(path, "w") as f:`

Comment: Fixed. Sorry it slipped past me